# Android Java Adapter, PHP JSON

Tags: java, php, android, json

**Can someone give me a example of a right json file and php, so I can use it in the Android GET method? I think my files are wrong. This are the newest files regarding JSON and PHP**

**data.json**

```html
{
 "Heroes":
 [
  {
   "name":"Superman",
   "about":"testdesc",
   "image":"google.de/image.png"
  
  },
  {
   "name":"Superman",
   "about":"testdesc",
   "image":"google.de/image.png"
  
  },
  {
   "name":"Superman",
   "about":"testdesc",
   "image":"google.de/image.png"
  
  },
  {
   "name":"Superman",
   "about":"testdesc",
   "image":"google.de/image.png"
  
  }
 ]






}
```

**data.php**

```html
<?php

$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json = json_encode($jsonData,true);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;




 ?>
```

I am new to Android App's coding.

May you can help me out, with a stupid problem.
I've tried to make an app from a youtube tutorial,
there it workes fine but I got several problems now I really need to fix.

The app is basicly an App that shows me a RecyclerViewCard with an Image, HeaderText and About text, the content is in a php file on my localhost.

```html
<?php

$json2 = array(
  "error" => "false",
  "Heroes" => array(
    'name' => 'Spiderman',
    'about' => 'Spiderman ist ein Spinnenheld mit einem leckeren Schwanz',
    'image' => 'www.google.de/info.png'
  )
);


 ?>
```

So this is basicly the Json code to get it in my app, I hope this is right. If not please help me out with the right json code.

The error I get is following:

```html
06-29 18:03:47.292 5249-5249/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-29 18:03:47.293 5249-5249/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
06-29 18:03:47.714 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/de.example.kevin.superheroes-2/lib/x86
06-29 18:03:47.764 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-29 18:03:47.954 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-29 18:03:48.574 5249-5287/de.example.kevin.superheroes D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-29 18:03:48.639 5249-5285/de.example.kevin.superheroes I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-29 18:03:48.639 5249-5285/de.example.kevin.superheroes D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-29 18:03:48.647 5249-5285/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
06-29 18:03:48.647 5249-5285/de.example.kevin.superheroes D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
06-29 18:03:48.949 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at de.example.kevin.superheroes.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:60)
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at de.example.kevin.superheroes.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:55)
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
06-29 18:03:49.168 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
06-29 18:03:49.169 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
06-29 18:03:49.169 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-29 18:03:49.169 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-29 18:03:49.169 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
06-29 18:03:49.169 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-29 18:03:49.169 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-29 18:03:49.169 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-29 18:03:49.240 5249-5249/de.example.kevin.superheroes W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

The MainActivity:

```html
package de.example.kevin.superheroes;

import android.app.LauncherActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView = null;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = null;
    private List<ListItem> listItems = null;
    private static final String URL_DATA = "http://192.168.178.29/android/data.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();


    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Content is loading ...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Heroes");

                    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                o.getString("name"),
                                o.getString("about"),
                                o.getString("image")
                        );

                        listItems.add(item);

                    }

                    adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

ListItem.java

```html
package de.example.kevin.superheroes;



import android.widget.ImageView;


public class ListItem {

    public ListItem(String img_url, String head, String desc) {
        this.img_url = img_url;
        this.head = head;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    private String  img_url = null;
    private String head = null;
    private String desc = null;

    public String getImg_url() {
        return img_url;
    }

    public String getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

MyAdapter

```html
package de.example.kevin.superheroes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;



public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem> listItems = null;
    private Context context = null;

    public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView textViewHead = null;
        public TextView textViewDesc = null;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);


        }
    }
}
```

I would be so glad if you can help me !

If you have any question please ask.

Thanks

---

After editing my json code I get following error:
PHP

```html
<?php



$json2  = array(
  "error" => "false",
  "Heroes" => array(
    'name' => 'Spiderman',
    'about' => 'Spiderman ist ein Spinnenheld mit einem ',
    'image' => 'www.google.de/info.png'
  )
);

echo json_encode($json2);
 ?>
```

No I get this huge errors :

I have postet it on pastebin because its to big for here:
https://pastebin.com/RAuNfZGm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it says, "org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0". It essentially means that you are not returning anything from your php. Like Vaibhav said, you need to encode your array in json using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and echo the result.

**Further Answer**

You would need,

```
<?php
class Hero {
            // Creating some properties
            public $name;
            public $about;
            public $image;

            // Assigning the values
            public function __construct($name, $about, $image) {
              $this->name = $name;
              $this->about = $about;
              $this->image = $image;
            }
}

$array_heros[0] = new Hero('Spiderman', 'Spiderman-about', 'image_link');
$array_heros[1] = new Hero('Batman', 'Batman-about', 'image_link');
$json2  = array(
  "error" => "false",
  "Heroes" => $array_heros
);

echo json_encode($json2);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After I changed it, i have got now a huge error code. I have added it on the bottom on my post, its on pastebin because its to huge for here.

Comment: You are getting `{"name":"Spiderman","about":"Spiderman ist ein Spinnenheld mit einem leckeren Schwanz","image":"www.google.de\/info.png"}` as json response, which is not an array but a json object. So when you parse it as json array, it falls in an exception.
Hope it helps.

Comment: So how do I make it to a Array?
This should probably solve my problems?! Hope so

Comment: I have done an array in a json file. So now I get an array

Comment: Is it possible to make an json file and do the same ? Like i have an json file as you can see at the start of my post and i would love to "import" it into the php file

Comment: yes, you can easily import any php file in another php file with, `require_once 'data.php'; ` in file where you would need it.

Comment: I would strongly advice you to go through basics of php atleast.

Comment: I do know php well, but not JSON. I tried it a few hours ago.
Thank you sooooo much.

Answer (score 0):

In you php file its just creating array not json 
to create json and return it use last line.

```
`
<?php

$json2 = array(
  "error" => "false",
  "Heroes" => array(
    'name' => 'Spiderman',
    'about' => 'Spiderman ist ein Spinnenheld mit einem leckeren Schwanz',
    'image' => 'www.google.de/info.png'
  )
);

echo json_encode($json2);
 ?>`
```

Comment: Thanks,  now I can see in the error log the items of the json. But I got probably thousands of error now. I will post it above.